# zebra bluetooth printer ZQ5221

Tags: android, bluetooth, zebra-striping

I am printing bitmap in zebra printer using Android phone but the printer is not printing image.it is printing some junk data.

I am not using any zebra official library and I do not want to use any library.
My bluetooth code is working perfectly correct in other printer ,but in zebra printer Image is not printing.

I have drawable and I would like to print it on zebra ,kindly help me

I tried many ways but nothing works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code is not required here .this is android native developement.most of them uses same code for bluetooth and my code is working fine in most of the bluetooth printer that I tested.

Comment: @VishwanathKumbar a code snippet could help experts on the ZQ5221 to see if you are missing some settings for this specific sensor. Without that there is no way to tell if your code has an issue or your printer is simply faulty